# Moving resources from disabled to new subscription in Azure

Tags: azure

I've got all my stuff under a subscription that got disabled (changed the employer). I registered a new one (pay-as-you-go on my own credit card). Attempting to move the deactivated sites to the new one failed and the portal says:

> Resources cannot be moved from disabled subscriptions.

I've followed [the link provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources) and googled around finding that ["*...source and destination subscriptions must be active..."*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#checklist-before-moving-resources). That's not very helpful in my case as I have no means to make the admins managing the old subscription reactivate it, not even for a short while.

Do I have to scratch everything and re-publish the application? It won't let me do that on the same URL (and re-configurating the SQL server/DB might cause addition issues). Google gave me nada and I wonder if there's a way to simply move the stuff somehow in the portal.

I can't [wait for the reply from MS support](https://serverfault.com/questions/857584/how-do-i-transfer-a-resource-group-from-a-disabled-subscription) because the site manages a register for people with some mental disabilities and not being able to access the material is a huge blow on their daily peace.

Oh, I'm running the site pro-bono (out of my own  pocket for the unfortunate souls) so a solution that's pricey might be a show-stopper.

Comment: Unfortunately this really is a question for Billing Support, and your old employer. Doubtful there's anything that can be done if you've been blocked from your original subscription (aside from requesting those resources from your older employer). But if you already have all the code, database, etc, I would think you could re-deploy? As far as the URL: If the site has been torn down, then all the namespaces are released. And if you own the custom URL, you can map it to your new Azure deployment.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I was unclear. Sorry. The account is mine, the URL is owned by me, the source code etc are mine too. I had them before I joined the employer, in fact. They are merely a part in this by letting me use the subscription key for the time being. Hopefully, they'll unlock the stuff for a few days so I can point that to my next employer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me. Go to the subscription and reactive it by converting it to a pay-as-you-go subscription. Then you can download and move resources. If you don't need the subscription after that, you can delete it.